# Angularjs apply additional selections to filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater and am using the filter to filter a query, such as

`ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query"`

I've added a select option and want to add that as an additional filter.

Any suggestions as to how to add this in conjunction with the current filter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilterFunc"
```

where

```
$scope.myFilterFunc = function (item) {
  //return true or false depending on multiple conditions
};
```

You have access to `item` as well as anything on the `$scope` within that function. With some `if` statements, you should be able to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Hm, so I think I would need to watch the change of the select box, but It's already being watched in a directive that serves another purpose, it seems you can't watch the same model twice?

Comment: I don't think you will need to watch it. You can just use it in the filtering function and when the value of it changes, it should get picked up automatically by Angular.